# Blender doesn't follow the coordination of objects. What am I missing?

Tags: objects

On the left-hand side, you can see that x = 0 and y = 0 but the object is shifted and It's not related to the grid (x-axis and y-axis). It's not in the center. The same issue happens with the z-axis. The object is way above the grid although z = 0 or even a negative value. I think I'm missing something but I don't know what it is. [image]

Comment: Those are delta values for the transform operation, not absolute coordinates in scene space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So check this image please...

[image]

...by hitting a "T" key You could switch the *left panel* and by hitting the "N" key You could switch the *right panel*. As could be seen on TOP of the *right panel*, there are values for **Location, Rotation and Scale** and these are of your interest! Hope it helps buddy.

Sincerely, Jan

Answer (score 1):

As @DuarteFarrajotaRamos mentioned in the comments, those values are [delta values for translating object](https://blenderartists.org/t/what-are-delta-transforms/586138). You can access the co-ordinates of the object by selecting the object, pressing the N key and under transform tab, you could see the co-ordinates of your object. You can change them as per your need.